# SQL to update an Oracle table based on another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have two tables in an Oracle database: `USERS` and `USERLOG`

- `USERS` contains all the systems user details (`IDCOL`, `EMAIL`, `ISLOCKED`, etc.)
- `USERLOG` is a log of when users logged onto a system (`USERID`, `LOGIN` (date field))

Key field: `USERS.IDCOL` = `USERLOG.USERID`

Removed users are deleted from the USERS table; therefore there will be some IDs in the `USERLOG` that won't match to the `USERS` table.

I want to do two things to the user list:

1. Lock any users who haven't accessed system in last 9 months (i.e. their ID doesn't appear in the `USERLOG` in the last 9 months, which I guess will use something like:

   ```
   months_between( SYSDATE , USERLOG.LOGIN ) <= 9
   ```
2. Lock any users that have only one entry in the `USERLOG`, as long as it isn't within the last month/30 days (i.e. when the account was created)

To lock a user I need to update the `USERS.ISLOCKED` column from `0` to `1`

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

months_between( SYSDATE , USERLOG.LOGIN ) <= 9

1) In this case, the userlog.login isn't from a single row, but the max login time among a series of logins. There are different ways to do this, but I think the below query captures the requirement more clearly. "All users where no login exists in the last 9 months"

```
select *
from   users usr
where  not exists (
    select 1
    from   userlog log
    where  usr.user_id  = log.user_id
      and  log.login    > add_months(sysdate,-9)
)
```

Check to make sure you are getting the users you are, looking for and convert this select to a delete.

2) This would be 2 different conditions to satisfy the two rules..

```
select *
from   users
where  not exists (
    select 1
    from   userlog
    where users.userid = userlog.userid
      and userlog.login > add_months(sysdate,-1)
) AND (
     1 = (select count(*)
     from   userlog
     where  users.userid = userlog.userid)
    )
```

Comment: Rajesh, I've edited your answer to update a couple of field names, and also corrected a couple of syntax issues in the 2nd code block, but otherwise spot on, thanks very much.

Comment: For some reason my edits haven't been accepted, in case others are using, in the second code block `add_months(sysdate-1)` needs a comma before the `-1` and a left parenthesis is needed before the `1 = (`

Answer (score 1):

Couldent test it but the first one

```
update users a 
set islocked = 1 
where exists (
    select  1
    from    userlog b
    where   a.idcol = b.userid
    group  by b.userid
    having  months_betwen(sysdte , max(userlog)) <= 9)
```

the second one, if i got it right, you want to lock users that have only one entrance from over 30 days ago .... if so then

```
update users set islocked = 1 
where idcol in (
    select  userid
    from    userlog
    group by userid
    having count(*) = 1
    and count(case when month_between(login , sysdate) < 1 then 1 else null end) = 0)
```

so i'm basically counting the entrances in the last month and overall.
syntax might be off, i cant run an example here.

Comment: haki, thanks for the response, Rajesh's worked spot on so I've accepted his, your answer was useful but apologies I don't have enough rep to "mark as useful". Thanks again.